# Redirect to random link on the same website (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, web

When `website.com/api` is loaded, it want it to redirect me to `website.com/i/random_image.jpg`.

I want to do this with JavaScript or PHP.

So then i need something to keep track of the random_images, and i need something to redirect me to a random image.

(This is my first post here on StackOwerflow, sorry if it was difficult to understand!)

**Edit**
I got the help i wanted. Thanks :)

Comment: Voted to close as it is a code request (_off-topic here_). Keep in mind that "__write/debug-my-code__", "__recommend/search-something-for-me__", "__tutorial__" requests and "__low-effort__", "__unclear__", "__opinion-based__", "**non-programming-related**" questions are [Off-Topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: For your next questions please, go to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) then read  [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask a Question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ok, I'll remeber that :)

Answer (score -1):

Prototype code in PHP:

```
<?php

function getHtml($site) {
    $ch = curl_init($site);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $content;
}

function redirectToRandomImage($site) {
    $html = getHtml($site);
    preg_match_all('/img\ssrc="(.+\..{3})"/', $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
    $rndIx = rand(0, count($matches) - 1);
    $newLink = "Location: {$site}{$matches[$rndIx][1]}";
    header($newLink);
}

redirectToRandomImage('http://www.whatever.eu');

?>
```